# Single page application losing authentication token cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, signalr, forms-authentication

*Apologies in advance for the wall of text below, but I wanted to be sure to include anything in the log that might be useful....*

I have an ASP.Net MVC application whose primary interface is a single-page application using SignalR. We are having occasional problems with things suddenly "not working" for users--the underlying reason is that they are no longer authenticated. I have an MVC request every minute to keep the session alive, and SignalR also has its own keep-alive every 5 minutes. It doesn't seem to be related to a specific time interval, because most of the time, users have the application open all day without problems. I have included an annotated sample of the IIS log on the web server below. The authentication token and session values have been shortened for readability. Notice that the authentication token is renewed several times without any problem. Then, all of the sudden, the browser no longer sends the authentication token.

```
+------------+----------+-----------+------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       date | time     | cs-method | cs-uri-stem                  | cs-username | cs(Cookie)                          | sc-status | comment                                                                                        |
+------------+----------+-----------+------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2015-11-04 | 10:54:30 | GET       | /                            | -           | -                                   |       302 | user requesting page for the first time; redirect to login page                                |
| 2015-11-04 | 10:54:30 | GET       | /Account/Login               | -           | -                                   |       200 | login page GET                                                                                 |
| 2015-11-04 | 10:54:46 | POST      | /Account/Login               | -           |                                     |       302 | login page POST; authenticate and redirect to content page                                     |
| 2015-11-04 | 10:54:46 | GET       | /                            | user123     | .VWRID=AAAA                         |       302 | content page GET; user is logged in                                                            |
| 2015-11-04 | 10:54:46 | GET       | /Account/SelectConfiguration | user123     | .VWRID=AAAA                         |       200 | user doing stuff; no problem                                                                   |
| 2015-11-04 | …        | …         | …                            | user123     | .VWRID=AAAA;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 | user doing stuff; no problem                                                                   |
| 2015-11-04 | 10:54:50 | GET       | /signalr/negotiate           | user123     | .VWRID=AAAA;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 | SignalR connection                                                                             |
| 2015-11-04 | 10:54:50 | GET       | /signalr/start               | user123     | .VWRID=AAAA;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 |                                                                                                |
| 2015-11-04 | 10:54:50 | POST      | /signalr/send                | user123     | .VWRID=AAAA;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 |                                                                                                |
| 2015-11-04 | 10:55:50 | POST      | /Home/CheckVersion           | user123     | .VWRID=AAAA;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 | keepalive for ASP.Net session; once/min                                                        |
| 2015-11-04 | …        | …         | …                            | user123     | .VWRID=AAAA;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 | user doing stuff; no problem                                                                   |
| 2015-11-04 | 10:59:50 | GET       | /signalr/ping                | user123     | .VWRID=AAAA;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 | SignalR keepalive; once/5 min                                                                  |
| 2015-11-04 | 11:00:50 | …         | …                            | user123     | .VWRID=AAAA;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 |                                                                                                |
| 2015-11-04 | 11:08:50 | POST      | /Home/CheckVersion           | user123     | .VWRID=AAAA;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 |                                                                                                |
| 2015-11-04 | 11:09:50 | POST      | /Home/CheckVersion           | user123     | .VWRID=AAAA;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 | renewed ASP.net token sent to client (?)                                                       |
| 2015-11-04 | 11:09:50 | GET       | /signalr/ping                | user123     | .VWRID=BBBB;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 | new ASP.net token sent to server                                                               |
| 2015-11-04 | 11:10:50 | POST      | /Home/CheckVersion           | user123     | .VWRID=BBBB;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 |                                                                                                |
| 2015-11-04 | 11:11:50 | POST      | /Home/CheckVersion           | user123     | .VWRID=BBBB;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 |                                                                                                |
| 2015-11-04 | …        | …         | …                            | user123     | .VWRID=BBBB;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 | user doing stuff; no problem                                                                   |
| 2015-11-04 | 11:24:32 | POST      | /signalr/send                | user123     | .VWRID=BBBB;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 |                                                                                                |
| 2015-11-04 | 11:24:50 | POST      | /Home/CheckVersion           | user123     | .VWRID=BBBB;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 | renewed ASP.net token sent to client (?)                                                       |
| 2015-11-04 | 11:24:50 | GET       | /signalr/ping                | user123     | .VWRID=CCCC;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 | new ASP.net token sent to server                                                               |
| 2015-11-04 | 11:25:50 | POST      | /Home/CheckVersion           | user123     | .VWRID=CCCC;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 |                                                                                                |
| 2015-11-04 | …        | …         | …                            | user123     | .VWRID=CCCC;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 | user doing stuff; no problem                                                                   |
| 2015-11-04 | …        | …         | …                            | user123     | .VWRID=CCCC;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 | same pattern continues, until…                                                                 |
| 2015-11-04 | 11:58:50 | POST      | /Home/CheckVersion           | user123     | .VWRID=EEEE;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 |                                                                                                |
| 2015-11-04 | 11:59:50 | POST      | /Home/CheckVersion           | user123     | .VWRID=EEEE;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 |                                                                                                |
| 2015-11-04 | 11:59:50 | GET       | /signalr/ping                | user123     | .VWRID=EEEE;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 |                                                                                                |
| 2015-11-04 | 12:00:50 | POST      | /Home/CheckVersion           | -           | -                                   |       302 | NO AUTHENTICATION COOKIE!                                                                      |
| 2015-11-04 | 12:00:50 | GET       | /Account/Login               | -           | -                                   |       200 | JSON request "redirected" but user never notified                                              |
| 2015-11-04 | 12:01:50 | POST      | /Home/CheckVersion           | -           |                                     |       302 |                                                                                                |
| 2015-11-04 | 12:01:50 | GET       | /Account/Login               | -           |                                     |       200 |                                                                                                |
| 2015-11-04 | …        | POST      | /Home/CheckVersion           | -           |                                     |       302 | same pattern…                                                                                  |
| 2015-11-04 | …        | GET       | /Account/Login               | -           |                                     |       200 |                                                                                                |
| 2015-11-04 | 12:04:49 | GET       | /signalr/ping                | -           |                                     |       200 | signalr keepalive returns HTTP 200 (?)…                                                        |
| 2015-11-04 | 12:05:50 | POST      | /Home/CheckVersion           | -           |                                     |       302 |                                                                                                |
| 2015-11-04 | 12:05:50 | GET       | /Account/Login               | -           |                                     |       200 |                                                                                                |
| 2015-11-04 | …        | POST      | /Home/CheckVersion           | -           |                                     |       302 |                                                                                                |
| 2015-11-04 | …        | GET       | /Account/Login               | -           |                                     |       200 |                                                                                                |
| 2015-11-04 | 12:16:43 | POST      | /signalr/send                | -           |                                     |       403 | … but signalr requests fail because they need to be authenticated                              |
| 2015-11-04 | …        | POST      | /signalr/send                | -           |                                     |       403 |                                                                                                |
| 2015-11-04 | 12:43:23 | POST      | /signalr/abort               | -           |                                     |       403 | at some point signalr aborts                                                                   |
| 2015-11-04 | 12:43:23 | GET       | /signalr/connect             | user123     | .VWRID=AAAA;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses1 |       200 | and reconnects with the ORIGINAL authentication token (?)                                      |
| 2015-11-04 | 12:43:23 | GET       | /                            | -           |                                     |       302 | User realizes there is a problem and refreshed the page, forcing the login process to initiate |
| 2015-11-04 | 12:43:23 | GET       | /Account/Login               | -           |                                     |       200 |                                                                                                |
| 2015-11-04 | 12:43:35 | POST      | /Account/Login               | -           |                                     |       302 |                                                                                                |
| 2015-11-04 | 12:43:35 | GET       | /                            | user123     | .VWRID=FFFF                         |       302 | and we're good again…                                                                          |
| 2015-11-04 | 12:43:36 | GET       | /Account/SelectConfiguration | user123     | .VWRID=FFFF                         |       200 |                                                                                                |
| 2015-11-04 | …        | …         | …                            | user123     | .VWRID=FFFF;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses2 |       200 |                                                                                                |
| 2015-11-04 | 15:43:02 | POST      | /Home/CheckVersion           | user123     | .VWRID=GGGG;+ASP.NET_SessionId=ses2 |       200 | still going strong nearly 2 hours later.                                                       |
+------------+----------+-----------+------------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The relevant part of the web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".VWRID" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" protection="All" requireSSL="true" />
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```

**Does anyone have any ideas what might be going on here and how to resolve?**

**[UPDATE]**

In looking at the logs, this only seems to be impacting users on IE 10. The SignalR transport mechanism being used there is *foreverFrame*. I am wondering if this is a SignalR bug with that transport. I am going to downgrade those client to use long polling and see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We removed the *foreverFrame* option for the SignalR transport and the problem went away. Seems to be a bug in SignalR.